# Jasmine Unit Testing: How can I spy on Function.prototype.call() in a function parameter that is passed to my method under test?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to use jasmine to test a function that takes in a Function parameter

```
var functionUnderTest = function(functionParameter) {
     functionParameter.call();
}
```

`functionParameter` above is a Javascript Function and the call method is the method defined on the [Function.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). How can I spy on the call property to make sure it's called?

The following doesn't seem to be working

```
it("should call the functionParameter passed to it", function() {
    var mockFunction = function() {};

    spyOn(mockFunction, 'call');
    functionUnderTest(mockFunction);

    expect(mockFunction.call).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

as it results in an:

```
Error: Expected spy call to have been called.
```

Presumably because the jasmine spy has it's own call() function.

I also tried this, but it isn't working either:

```
it("should call the functionParameter passed to it", function() {
    var mockFunction = function() {};

    spyOn(mockFunction.prototype, 'call');
    functionUnderTest(mockFunction);

    expect(mockFunction.prototype.call).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

this time, the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

with a callstack pointing to:

```
Expectation.toHaveBeenCalled
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I've been at this for hours and it seems like I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding of jasmine.

Comment: You should ignore how it's called, and just `expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Bergi, the following works:

```
it("should call the functionParameter passed to it", function() {
    var mockFunction = jasmine.createSpy('mockFunction')

    functionUnderTest(mockFunction);

    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```